# How to render the definition of a macro on the PDF output?

Tags: macros

For example we have a macro defined in a package as follows.

```
\newcommand{\test}{this is a test macro}
```

I want to render this definition on the PDF output as follows.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{test}
\begin{document}
Hi \somecommandtorendermacrodefinition{\test}
\end{document}
```

Such that I get

> Hi \newcommand{\test}{this is a test macro}

in the PDF output.

How to do this with minimal hassle? Is there a package to do so?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. By the time it gets to `\somcommand...` the definition has been read and it can't tell whether it was a `\def` or a `\newcommand` or a `\DeclareDocumentCommand` (from `xparse`)...

Comment: You might looking for `\texttt{\string\test: \meaning\test}`, but it won't output the `\newcommand` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert the definition of a macro into the document using the `\meaning` primitive. However you won't get the `\newcommand` syntax from it. You need to switch to `tt` font to get it correctly displayed, otherwise the backslashes and other character won't be displayed correctly. You can display the macro name using `\string`.

```
\newcommand*{\showmacro}[1]{\texttt{\string#1: \meaning#1 }
```

This will give you e.g. for `\label` the following output:

```
\label: macro:#1->\@bsphack \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{\@currentlabel }{\thepage }}}\@esphack
```

Note that many macros use further macros, especially if they have optional arguments or are "protected" macros. So sometimes only the first step will be shown.

A better definition might be to use `\csname .. \endcsname` internally and also allow macro names with `@` and spaces (protected macros define a second macro which includes a space at the end).

```
\newcommand*{\showmacro}[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname: \expandafter\meaning\csname#1\endcsname}
```

Examples:

```
\showmacro{nobreakspace}

\showmacro{nobreakspace }
```

will give:

```
\nobreakspace: macro:->\protect \nobreakspace  

\nobreakspace : \long macro:->\leavevmode \nobreak \
```

Note that there is also the [`texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) script which allows you to display macro definitions easily on the command line (However, I never tested it on non-Linux machines).

There is also the [`show2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/show2e) package which gives you `\showcmd` which will show the definition of a macro including its underlying sub-macros as debugging output, i.e. stops the compilation and displays them in the output window but not in the document.

Comment: `\relax` cannot be expanded anymore?

Comment: @xport: `\relax` is a primitive, so no, it can't be expanded.